# Number of subalgebras of dimension $e$ of a finite dimensional algebra over $F_q$ of dimension $d$

Tags: finite-fields, algebras

Let $F_q$ be a finite field of order $q$. Let $A$ be a finite dimensional algebra over $F_q$ of dimension $d$ and let $e < d$ be some positive integer. Then what is the number of sub-algebras of $A$ of dimension $e$?

For example consider the following algebra of $3 \times 3$ matrices:

$\left\{ \begin{pmatrix}a_0&a_1&b\\0&a_0&0\\0&c&d\end{pmatrix} \text{ $:$ $a_0, a_1, b, c, d \in F_q$} \right\}$ 
I want to count the number of 3-dimensional subalgebras of this algebra.

Comment: The answer, of course, depends on the algebra $A$. At the level of generality at which you pose your question, I am quite sure nothing can be said.

Answer (score 3):

If $A$ is a field of prime dimension $p$ over $F_q$, then it has exactly two subalgebras. If instead $A=(F_q)^p$ is a direct product of $p$ copies of $F_q$, then it has many more than $2^p-1$ subalgebras, many of which have the same dimension.

It follows from this that knowing just $d$, $w$ and $q$ one cannot answer your questoin.

Comment: Even if you assume that $A$ is a Galois field extension of $F_q$ of finite degree $d$, one cannot answer it.